# Check two dates are in same fiscal year in SQL condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

While creating a trigger restriction for restricting modification of data for the same financial year, I needed to check if 2 dates(NEW.starting_date  & OLD.starting_date ) lie in the same fiscal year or not under my condition section.

My table goes like this.

```
pid  (int)    |    data (varchar)      |   starting_date (date)

1             |          abc           |  2017-09-08
2             |          def           |  2017-03-13
3             |          ghi           |  2017-07-12
```

Condition

```
NEW.data<>OLD.data
  AND (
      (YEAR(NEW.starting_date) = YEAR(OLD.starting_date) 
AND MONTH(NEW.starting_date)<=4 AND MONTH(OLD.starting_date) <=4
AND MONTH(NEW.starting_date)>=3 AND MONTH(OLD.starting_date) >=3)

OR 

(ABS(YEAR(NEW.starting_date)-YEAR(OLD.starting_date)) = 1
AND MONTH(NEW.starting_date)<=3 AND MONTH(OLD.starting_date) >=4
AND MONTH(NEW.starting_date)>=4 AND MONTH(OLD.starting_date) <=3)
)

                                                                                              )
```

> NOTE: The financial year starts on April 1st each year.

QUESTION:

1. This condition is not working as expected. What could be the problem?
2. Is there any other efficient way to do this.

**DATABASE SERVER**

```
Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.1.25-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

**Web server**

```
Apache/2.4.26 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/5.6.31
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 76b08b24596e12d4553bd41fc93cccd5bac2fe7a $
```

Comment: We need a bit more info.  Please include the specific RDBMS utilized (assuming MySQL, given the tag, but confirm in the text, please), the schema for the tables involved, and a complete example showing what's not working as expected.  Consider reading [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056).

Comment: @hunteke info has been added

Comment: Good.  But we still need the other details: 1) The schema for the tables involved, 2) Specific code that you have tried 3) output showing exactly what is not working as you intend.

Comment: @hunteke for the question in hand, DB schema is completely irrelevant

Comment: You say that, but my thought process currently suggests otherwise.  Having a schema might help.  In this industry, it's often the "details that don't matter," that matter.  Regardless, we now have an answer, which hopefully helps his situation.

Comment: @hunteke How could it possibly matter? We're looking for a condition that checks if two dates are in the same fiscal year. The condition should work regardless of the schema or any other details. Also it's easy to see why the condition is not working as expected. The first part just checks if both dates are in either march or april. And the second part return always false because it checks if both months are 3 or less AND 4 or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of question - why is your condition not working as expected. In the first part where both dates are in the same year you are comparing only March and April. And the second part is just mixing previous and next year wrongly - you have to get rid of ABS and split in two OR conditions

Fix:

```
NEW.data<>OLD.data
AND 
(
   (
      YEAR(NEW.starting_date) = YEAR(OLD.starting_date) 
      AND
      ( 
         (MONTH(NEW.starting_date)<=3 AND MONTH(OLD.starting_date)<=3)
         OR
         (MONTH(NEW.starting_date)>=4 AND MONTH(OLD.starting_date)>=4)
      )
   )
   OR 
   (
      YEAR(NEW.starting_date)-YEAR(OLD.starting_date) = 1
      AND 
      MONTH(NEW.starting_date)<=3 AND MONTH(OLD.starting_date) >=4
   )
   OR
   (
      YEAR(NEW.starting_date)-YEAR(OLD.starting_date) = -1
      AND 
      MONTH(NEW.starting_date)>=4 AND MONTH(OLD.starting_date) <=3
   )
)
```

EDIT - for the second part of question - more efficient way of doing this, based on Samuil Banti's answer, converted to CASE statement:

```
NEW.data<>OLD.data
AND CASE WHEN MONTH(NEW.starting_date) >= 4 
           THEN YEAR(NEW.starting_date) ELSE YEAR(NEW.starting_date) - 1
    END 
= CASE WHEN MONTH(OLD.starting_date) >= 4 
           THEN YEAR(OLD.starting_date) ELSE YEAR(OLD.starting_date) - 1
    END
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, you just missed some parentheses in your 1st solution

Comment: actually there were some extra :) fixed now

Answer (score 2):

I can't do a test with a filter right now but here's a quick comparison  between the financial years for two dates:

```
SET @start_date = '2016-03-11';
SET @end_date = '2016-04-11';
SELECT IF(
(SELECT IF(MONTH(@start_date)>=4, YEAR(@start_date), YEAR(@start_date)-1))
=
(SELECT IF(MONTH(@end_date)>=4, YEAR(@end_date), YEAR(@end_date)-1))
, 'Same fiscal year', 'Different fiscal year');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the year of either one of your dates and then add `-04-01` to get a start or end date of the current financial year.

```
DATE(DATE_ADD(CONCAT(YEAR(NEW.starting_date),'-','04-01'), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
// OR
DATE(DATE_SUB(CONCAT(YEAR(NEW.starting_date),'-','04-01'), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
```

Then compare those values with `OLD.starting_date`