# how to get the rows where from_date and to_date are in same financial year

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, filter

I have a table `TargetOrder` which has from_date and to_date columns along with some other columns. I need to filter the rows whoose from_date and to_date are in the same financial year (1 Apr - 31 Mar).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the SO. 

How is the financial year defined in your system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check two dates are in same fiscal year in SQL condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46977408/check-two-dates-are-in-same-fiscal-year-in-sql-condition)

Comment: it is from 1st Apr to 31 march in the consecutive year.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = TargetOrder::whereBetween(DB::raw("DATE('from_date')"), array($from, $to))->whereBetween(DB::raw("DATE('to_date')"), array($from, $to));
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: The only tag of note is mysql - so this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

TargetOrder.from_date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '20100401', 112) AND
TargetOrder.to_date < CONVERT(DATETIME, '20110401', 112)

Comment: This is not working in MySQL, as the convert function takes only 2 arguments

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone for all your Efforts, I finally solved it.

```
select * from TargetOrder
where year(date_add(from_date, INTERVAL 9 MONTH)) != year(date_add(to_date, INTERVAL 9 MONTH));
```

please post if you have any other work arounds.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).